# Insert row into a view

Tags: 7, views

I have a view which fetches nodes from content type A, arranges them in a grid and uses a displaysuite buildmode to render them...nothing fancy so far. Now I want to insert a specific node of content type B at a specific position in the grid...like this:

```
+----------+----------+
|          |          |
|  type A  |  type A  |
|          |          |
+----------+----------+
|          |          |
|  type B  |  type A  |
|          |          |
+----------+----------+
|  type A  |  type A  |
.          .          .
```

I'm not sure where to start. I was hoping there would be some hook, preprocess function or whatever where I get an array of node objects to insert my special node into which then gets rendered...

Comment: I think that you can create a View with your two content types, and in the template of the view, use the array of the items (or create a new array) to control the sort that do you want.

It's an idea, so I can not give you any information about performance area. 

Also review this, I guess that could give an idea http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8898/views-sticky-items-per-page-paginated-using-several-displays-hooks-or-ui-way

Comment: Thanks for your comment! That pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the function I was looking for. You can insert nodes in the results array just after the query has been executed.

This goes in the module:

```
function modulename_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  // wait for the right view
  if($view->name == "name_of_the_view") {
    // create the object you want to insert in the result
    $temp = new stdClass;
    // creation date of that node   
    $temp->node_created = 1314807643;
    // nodeID
    $temp->nid = 13;

    $new_result_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($view->result as $single_result) {
      if($i == 2) {
        // insert the extra node at 3rd position
        $new_result_array[] = $temp;
        $new_result_array[] = $single_result;
      } else {
        $new_result_array[] = $single_result;
      }
      $i++;
    }
    // replace the old result array
    $view->result = $new_result_array;
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting solution!

Answer (score 1):

For any latecomers to this question, there's a module that does just this [Views Row Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_row_insert)

It has it's limitations when you start to push it, but it would do just as OP requests with very minimal effort and no hooks needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also using views theming feature. Place PHP file `views-view-unformatted--taxonomy-term--page.tpl.php` right in your theme's folder and with this code you can print custom code after every 3th row for *Taxonomy term page* default views:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ($id == 2): ?>**My custom code after first row in Drupal views**<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This line does the trick

```
<?php if ($id == 2): ?>**My custom code after first row in Drupal views**<?php endif; ?>
```

[Source and more details](http://www.jasom.net/how-to-add-custom-code-adsense-after-first-row-in-drupal-7-and-drupal-8-views-one-line-solution).