# Add data to JSON generated by views_datasource

Tags: 7

I'm using "views datasource" to output a view as JSON - for each views row it's creating a JSON object with the fields as string/value pairs - all those objects are in an array which is the value to a string specified by the "Root object name" in the view's format settings. It looks like this:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {
      "nodeid":"1",
      "title":"foo"
    },
    {
      "nodeid":"2",
      "title":"bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to add another string/value pair to the main JSON object so it looks like this:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {
      "nodeid":"1",
      "title":"foo"
    },
    {
      "nodeid":"2",
      "title":"bar"
    }
  ],
  "total_nodes":"2",
  "some_other_stuff":"here"
}
```

In [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/insert-row-into-a-view) I found out how I could add elements to the view's results but now I need to add elements "next to" the view's results. I just don't know where I need to put my code. Can anyone point me to a hook that would do the trick?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just have to use the same hook as in the other post, but just cange the structure of the new result array. I didn't test this, but chances are good that adding a new element to the `$view->result` object won't do any harm.

Comment: It won't do any harm but it won't solve my problem either :) Everything I do to $view->result only affects the JSON array that is the value for "nodes" but instead I want to add a new string/value pair at the same level as "nodes"

Comment: So then you could implement something in the view template for the JSON display, but I don't know if there's one. The correct file to modify seems to be `views-views-json-style-simple.tpl.php`.

Comment: Great...that's exactly the right place! You might want to post that as an answer :)

Comment: Done. See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement something in the view template for the JSON display.

The correct file to modify seems to be views-views-json-style-simple.tpl.php.

You have to copy it to your theme's template folder (usually template's root directory, or `template` subdirectory) and add the necessary data to the `$json` variable before the correct `print $json` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up doing the changes in the preprocess function for that template file since I want to have this in a module and not a theme. The function is `modulename_preprocess_views_views_json_style_simple(&$vars)`

Comment: Glad you managed to make it work, and took time to complete the information. Have a nice day.

Comment: Great solution !! for people interested, on modulename_preprocess_views_views_json_style_simple(&$vars) alter the key $vars['rows'], i'm using this with a search api view for adding facets filters