# Multiple images in field and views

Tags: views, media

I have a view that creates JSON for me. The view has a field that multiple images, title, body and some other data fields on it. The image field can have multiple images. How can I show  all the images? I know multiple field settings would show all the images but then it would loop all the info multiple times (as many times as there images) and I don't want this to happend.

I have also tried "Display all values in the same row" and putting Simple separator as "," but it only shows the first image.

What I want is the JSON would be something like this:

```
"nodes" : [

{
  "nid" : "124",
  "title" : "This is the node title",
  "field_shot_desc" : "Short description text",
  "Body" : "<p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>\n",
  "field_images" : "http://www.domain.com/sites/mytheme/files/styles/browser-thumb/public/rest1.jpg","http://www.domain.com/sites/mytheme/files/styles/browser-thumb/public/rest2.jpg",

},
```

So the images would be separated with , or something so I can manipulate them in JS later.

Comment: Please post the current output also.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a piece of code I wrote for the same problem. It checks if the field is an array and start a for loop to print the field. I've used this in an external page who gets json through a json view from drupal.
I hope this can help you. If you rewrite it in a simple way, please let me know.
I'm using drupal 6, with NO "Display all values in the same row".

This Check if the field has got more than one img:

```
var image =  your_img_field;
    function isArray(image) {
   if (image.constructor == Object) 
      return true;
   else 
      return false;
}
```

If the field has got more than one img, it counts the array and return the size:

```
if (isArray(image) == true) {
Object.size = function(image) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in image) {
        if (image.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
var size = Object.size(image);
```

Here the for loop to print (in my views the array starts from 1)

```
for (i=1; i<size+1;i++){
$("ul").append("<li><img src=\'"+image[i]+"\' /></li>");
}
}
```

If the field img has not more than 1 img it prints the single img.

```
else {
$("ul").append("<li><img src=\'"+image+"\' /></li>");
}
```

PLEASE, CHECK QUOTES AND DOUBLE QUOTES IN THE IMG TAG `<img src=\'"+image+"\' />`

Comment: So I think i would need to make a custom module for this? I'm not that experienced with Drupal. I have done mostly admin stuff with it.

Comment: Where are you using it and why?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the view template to rewrite the output to fit your needs.

[This thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26862/add-data-to-json-generated-by-views-datasource/26911#26911) has the information you need to find the correct file, but your use will be slightly different.

It only involves simple PHP string manipulation, probably with an `implode` somewhere.