# Display a promo image at last in every slideshow created for a node

Tags: 7, views

I am using [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module to display multiple images uploaded in my `article` content type.
Every node landing page will have a slideshow displayed with its images (slideshow works fine).
All what I need is one common(Promo)Image to display as the last image/slide in every slideshow.

Is this possible with "Views Slideshow" and "Views" ? Do I need to create a separate tpl file for this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Promo article and add the promo image as the field in this article.

Note the this article will be just a placeholder for us and will not be presented anywhere. So may you could un-publish as well.

Do a dpm to find out the fid or any related that you need to know about this particular image field. Then make changes to the view in post_execute.

```
   function modulename_views_post_execute(&$view) {
      // wait for the right view
      if($view->name == "name_of_the_view") {
        // create the object you want to insert in the result
        // dpm($view->result); to check how the objects are built. 
        $temp = new stdClass;
        $promo_image->fid = 13;

        // replace the old result array
        $view->result[] = $promo_image;
      }
    }
```

Based on the answer : [Insert row into a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/insert-row-into-a-view)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Gokul,I will update you soon on this.