# How to create a view grid that changes content type per row

Tags: views, display-suite, nodes

Goal: **Create a Grid that shows mixed content types and have control how those types are added to grid (ie. by row)**

I have 3 content types and would like control over how they are added to a view.

Case 1: inject a row of Content Type B or C into a view of Type A based on row number.

Case 2: intersperse view with (possibly random) Content type C (think adding images to liven it up.)

Some approaches I've explored:

- [Display Suite View Display](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)
- Views Context Display
- Panels with Context
- Views embeded in views
- [NodeQueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue)

For case 1 I could just create seperate blocks but then I need to keep the view order consistent (perahps using nodequeue?) across blocks.  Do I need to pass the current node queue position as an argument to each block?

For case 2 how do I insert Content Type C images every few rows?  (I could even use css but need the grid to wrap around it.)

**Important note: I'm a system builder, not a developer so prefer something that can be maintained without managing custom code but a basic views template would be fine.**

**Case 1**

Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type C
Content Type C
Content Type C
Content Type C
Content Type C
Content Type A

**Case 2**

Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type C
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type C
Content Type A
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type C
Content Type B
Content Type B
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type C
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type A
Content Type C
Content Type A
Content Type A

Comment: It gets even worse as Views is not letting me mix hte content types.  https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view could be helpful, but what I'd really like is to create a View that acts as a Content Type to views.  This way I could do the ordering and avoid having to code a template to insert.

Answer (score 1):

sounds doable with [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view), I have done something a bit similar using Views Field View with Contextual filters. if it did't work the way you want, so you need to code it checkout [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/insert-row-into-a-view)